# How to write a Pydantic model to accept a Dictionary of Dictionaries

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

The code below is modified [from the Pydantic documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/)
I would like to know how to change `BarModel` and `FooBarModel` so they accept the input assigned to `m1`. I have tried using `__root__` and syntax such as `Dict[str, BarModel]` but have been unable to find the magic combination.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class BarModel(BaseModel):
    whatever: float
    foo: str

class FooBarModel(BaseModel):
    banana: str
    bar: BarModel

m = FooBarModel(banana='a', bar={'whatever': 12.3, 'foo':'hello'})
m1 = FooBarModel({
  'a':{'whatever': 12.3, 'foo':'hello'},
  'b':{'whatever': 12.4, 'foo':'bye'}
})

print(m.dict())   # returns a dictionary:
print(m1.dict())  # TypeError
```

The final solution will be deployed in a FastAPI context.

Comment: Have got the above working using __root__={} syntax but still unable to apply it to FastAPI. This bug looks relevant https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/911

Answer (score 11):

If all you're trying to do is have a dictionary of `BarModel`'s in another model, this answers your question:

```py
from typing import Dict
from pydantic import BaseModel

class BarModel(BaseModel):
    whatever: float
    foo: str

class FooBarModel(BaseModel):
    dictionaries: Dict[str, BarModel]

m1 = FooBarModel(dictionaries={
    'a': {'whatever': 12.3, 'foo': 'hello'},
    'b': {'whatever': 12.4, 'foo': 'bye'}
}

print(m1.dict())
```

Comment: This is working for me. Also I realised that with __root__ my original data can be passed in without the keyword argument. There is still an issue to do with how BarModel is exported in FastAPI, but I am slowly unravelling the pieces. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

You already found your magic combination, you haven't realized it yet.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Dict

class BarModel(BaseModel):
    whatever: float
    foo: str

class FooBarModel(BaseModel):
    banana: str
    bar: Dict[str, BarModel]


m1 = FooBarModel(banana="a", bar={
  'a':{'whatever': 12.3, 'foo':'hello'},
  'b':{'whatever': 12.4, 'foo':'bye'}
})

assert m1.dict() == {'banana': 'a', 'bar': {'a': {'whatever': 12.3, 'foo': 'hello'}, 'b': {'whatever': 12.4, 'foo': 'bye'}}}
```

This runs without any errors.

Note that we still have banana, if you want to discard it, simply delete.

If you wanted use pure typing and some static analyzer your examples would evaluate to this

```py
from typing import Dict, Union
m = FooBarModel(banana='a', bar={'whatever': 12.3, 'foo':'hello'})


m: Dict[str, Union[str, Dict[str, Union[float, str]]]]
```

But what you want is actually this

```py
from typing import Dict, Union

m1 = FooBarModel({
  'a':{'whatever': 12.3, 'foo':'hello'},
  'b':{'whatever': 12.4, 'foo':'bye'}
})

m1: Dict[str, Union[str, Dict[str, Dict[str, Union[float, str]]]]]
```